# How to Generate Dynamic URL Structure with Multiple Segments in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Question:

I'm working on a project where I need to create a dynamic URL structure in Next.js 13 with multiple segments. Specifically, I want to achieve the following structure: hubs/[hub]/[guide]/[chapter]. I need to be able to access each page within that route.

I've consulted the official Next.js documentation, particularly the section on Generating Dynamic Routes with Multiple Segments. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

However, the documentation primarily covers scenarios with two levels of depth.

Could someone please guide me on how to create this more complex dynamic folder structure with multiple segments?

What are the necessary files and configurations needed for this kind of dynamic routing?
Are there any specific considerations or best practices I should be aware of for handling multiple dynamic segments in a route?
I appreciate any insights or code examples that can help me implement this URL structure effectively. Thank you for your assistance!